# Why ping (ICMP) generates ESP traffic?

Tags: networking, icmp, ipsec

I'm reading this  article on wikipedia about protocols (OSI model) [1]

It says that ICMP(aka ping) and IPsec are at Layer 3(Network Layer). And ESP is at Layer 4(Transport Layer).

When I use strongSwan [2] on two machines and I have an established connection between the two of them, and I use ping command from one machine to another, in wireshark I see ESP packets and when I decrypt the ESP packets, they are in fact ICMP packets.

Why is this happening?

[1] : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_network_protocols_(OSI_model)

[2] : https://www.strongswan.org/